# How to check that two matrices are similar?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have two matrices. Is there any command to show these two matrices are similar? I searched but I couldn't find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: If they're exact or symbolic matrices, check the result of `JordanDecomposition[]`. Use `SchurDecomposition[]` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Jordan normal form provided by `JordanDecomposition`...

```
n = 15;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
g = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
c = LinearSolve[g, a].g;
Max[Abs[JordanDecomposition[a][[2]] - JordanDecomposition[b][[2]]]] < 10^-12
Max[Abs[JordanDecomposition[a][[2]] - JordanDecomposition[c][[2]]]] < 10^-12

(* False *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: `JordanDecomposition[]` is unreliable in the inexact case [if the matrices to be compared are very nearly defective](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=X5YfsuCWpxMC&pg=PA354). Compare the results of `SchurDecomposition[]` instead.

Comment: @J.M. Hm. In my example, `a` and `c` are similar but I see no coincidences in the Schur decompositions... Schur decomposition is a normal form only for conjugacy under orthogonal transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the Eigenvalues of both matrices are the same, and if both matrices are Diagonalizable . To do so you could create two functions that does this and combine them like this:

```
l[x_, y_] := (If[Length[Eigenvalues[x]] == Length[Eigenvalues[y]], If[Sort[Eigenvalues[x]] == Sort[Eigenvalues[y]], True, False], 
    False]);
r[x_, y_] := (If[Det[Eigenvectors[x]] != 0 && Det[Eigenvectors[y]] != 0, True, 
    False]);
AreSimilar[x_, y_] := (If[l[x, y] == True && r[x, y] == True, True, False]);
```